# Only keep first value of first column and sort the two other columns according to hierarchy

Tags: postgresql, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

So five people work at the Laugh factory. Marc is up first, then Judy, then Lorie, then Agnes and lastly, Isaiah.

I want to go from this:

```
+------------------------------+
| Laugh Factory |Marc | Judy   |
| Laugh Factory |Judy | Lorie  |
| Laugh Factory |Lorie| Agnes  |
| Laugh Factory |Agnes| Isaiah |
+------------------------------+
```

To this:

```
 Laugh Factory | Marc | Judy | Lorie | Agnes | Isaiah
```

How do I achieve that?

Comment: Sure, that will do too. Ideally, I'd want arrows as delimiters but that seems to impossible to format to.

Comment: What are the column names of that table?

Comment: So what I will do is use a recursive function in order to get that result. The table really is information about the comedian and the preceding comedian. So Marc has null value in the preceding comedian column.  The table I wrote out is what I am outputting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a [recursive query](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) for that.

Something along the lines (untested):

```sql
with recursive tree as (
  select company, comedian, preceding_comedian, 1 as level
  from the_table
  where company = 'Laugh Factory'
    and preceding_comedian is null
  union all
  select ch.company, ch.comedian, ch.preceding_comedian, p.level + 1
  from the_table ch
    join tree p on ch.preceding_comedian = p.comedian
)
select company, string_agg(comedian, ' > ' order by level) as comedians
from tree 
group by company;
```

Comment: @Synchrowave: that's the number `1` and is used to keep the ordering of the elements

Comment: A couple of things that I do not understand. 1. What is table ch? 2. What is "tree p"?

Comment: Is there a way to display the amount of comedians? Like by using the sum of level? I can't figure that out..